# How can I bundle socket.io-client with webpack?

Tags: socket.io, angular, webpack

I am new to webpack and having issues bundling socket.io-client with webpack. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am using Angular 2 RC.1

package.json

```
...."dependencies": {
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"core-js": "^2.3.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.7",
"zone.js": "~0.6.12",
"socket.io": "^1.4.6"
}....
```

typings.json

```
  ...."ambientDependencies": {
"socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654",....
```

socket.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
require ('socket.io-client/socket.io');

@Component({
    selector: 'socket',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/socket/socket.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/components/socket/socket.css'],
})
export class SocketTest {
socket = null;

constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
  ....
```

errors:

```
    ./~/socket.io-client/socket.io.js
Critical dependencies:
1:475-482 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is     possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better     results.
 @ ./~/socket.io-client/socket.io.js 1:475-482
browser_adapter.js:86 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION:     Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: io is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: io is not defined....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your webpack.config.js, add socket.js as an external library so it doesn't get packed with the rest of your javascript,

Of course, you need to actually merge these settings with your angular ones.

```
external:{
    ...
    'socket.io-client':'io'
}

resolve: {
    alias: {
        ...
        'socket.io-client': path.join( __dirname, 'node_modules', 'socket.io-client', 'socket.io.js' )
    }
},
module: {
    ...
    noParse: [ /socket.io-client/ ]
}
```

Then in your index.html, include

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
```

And require it as:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
require ('io');

@Component({
    selector: 'socket',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/socket/socket.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/components/socket/socket.css'],
})
```

P.S. I haven't tried these settings myself, I just wanted to at least put you on the right track.

Comment: I believe there's a typo on "external" => "externals"