# How to bundle third party library with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescript project with some external dependencies. One of them is socke.io-client. I use amd module system.

I've downloaded typings for socke.io-client, which declares an ambient module like this:

```
declare module 'socket.io-client' {...}
```

In production I compile all my source .ts files into one prod.js file.

How can I build my project to concatenate this deps inside this prod.js file, so end users don't have to include something manually using require.js or similar tool? Think of "static linking" in c++

Comment: You will need to use webpack or another tool to bundle third party libraries https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: I mean well, how should I reference such a module? I can't use relative module name, bacause it will not resolve to ambient module declaration..

Comment: ok. if you are not using modules, you don't need to import the "socket.ioiclient" module, just use the "io(...)" function directly. Make sure to have a referente to the typing... something like this: 

/// <reference path="path/to/socket.io-client.d.ts" />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I bundle socket.io-client with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058080/how-can-i-bundle-socket-io-client-with-webpack)